# C# WPF AutoCompleteBox: How to bind text programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, autocompletebox

From XAML I am able to create and give values to the properties of AutoCompleteBox but I want to do it programmatically.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace comboboxSuggestions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var mylist = new List<person>
                             {
                                 new person()
                                 {
                                     name = "vikas",
                                     lastName = "bansal"
                                 },
                                  new person()
                                 {
                                     name = "viksit",
                                     lastName = "bansal"
                                 },
                                  new person()
                                 {
                                     name = "sunil",
                                     lastName = "bansal"
                                 }
                             };

            autocompleteBox.ItemsSource = mylist;
            autocompleteBox.ValueMemberPath = "name";
            var binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("name")
            {
            };
            autocompleteBox.SetBinding(AutoCompleteBox.TextProperty, binding);
        }

        private void autocompleteBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (autocompleteBox.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                person s = autocompleteBox.SelectedItem as person;

                string lastName = s.lastName;
            }
        }
    }

    public class person
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
    }


}
```

**XAML File**

```
   <Controls:AutoCompleteBox Name="autocompleteBox" SelectionChanged="autocompleteBox_SelectionChanged"
                                      Height="30" Width="200" 
                                      />
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: What part(s) of the c# code aren't working?

Comment: I have updated the question and provided whole code. @GordonAllocman

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `ItemsSource` is a `List<person>`, but you haven't provided an `ItemTemplate` that tells the `AutoCompleteBox` what to display for each `person`. When you see "comboboxSuggestions.person", that's because the default `ItemTemplate` is just doing `person.ToString()`.

Here's how you would resolve this:

First, add a `fullname` property to `person`, like this:

```
public class person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }

    public string fullname => name + " " + lastname;
}
```

Then, define an `ItemTemplate` within your XAML, like this:

```
<Controls:AutoCompleteBox Name="autocompleteBox"
                          SelectionChanged="autocompleteBox_SelectionChanged"
                          Height="30"
                          Width="200">
    <Controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding fullname}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    <Controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
</Controls:AutoCompleteBox>
```

(Apologies if there are any typos, I haven't tested this code.)

---

**Edit**

To avoid defining a template in XAML, you could just override `ToString()` for `person` instead.

```
public class person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name + " " + lastname;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually i want to bind text from code instead of writing it to xaml. I am trying to create a extension function so that i do not have to write so much xaml :) because there are more than 30 boxes are there in actual project

Comment: Ahh, well I think you could just override `ToString` for `person`, and that would do the trick. I'll modify my answer to show how that would be done.

Comment: but what if I need to bind the model with many `autocompleteboxexs` with different properties?? Just mentioning again that I do not want to write `{binding xyz}` in xaml, I need todo it from backend code